# Can I limit the size of MFC CString buffer

Tags: string, mfc, size, buffer, limit

I have an old application which uses CString through out the code. 
Maximum size of the string which is written to CString is 8,9 characters, but I noticed that it allocates more. (at least 128 bytes per CString)

Is there a way to limit the size of CString buffer. Fox example to 64bytes?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is this really a problem ?

Comment: Yes if you have 10 million objects with 4 CString objects each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In detail:
The CString implementation is internal. You find the code in CSimpleStringT::PrepareWrite2 and in the Reallocate function of the string manager.

PrepareWrite2 allocates the buffer. If there was no buffer before, it requests the exact size. If the buffer is changes. The buffer is newLength*1.5.

Finally the request is passed to the Reallocate function of the string manager. Finally this size is passed to the CRT function realloc.

Keep in mind that the memory manager itself decides again what blocksize is "effective" and might change the size again.

So as I see (in VS-2013/VS-2010) you have no chance to change the blocksize. The job is finally done by realloc. And even this function passes its request to HeapAlloc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have to rework the code and replace the CStrings. I did one additional test and I see that when I place 3 characters in CString allocated buffer is 64 bytes.

Comment: Debug or Release? Even if you replace it. Finally the segments get allocated by the internal heap. And this module controls the 64 Bytes. I think this is the smallest allocatable block. Less would cause more fragmentation! My tip: Don't think and worry about this. There are well determined reasons about this, and years of experience.